# How to get rid of page margins using Neat and Bourbon

Tags: css, bourbon, neat

Using Bourbon and Neat, it seems to add an 8 pixel pad around the page by default. What is the solution to get rid of that padding and make the page content extend to use the entire width and height of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `reset` stylesheet is something that you should always include as a part of your stylesheets. This idea was originally proposed by [Eric Meyer in 2007](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/).

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

His stylesheet has been ported to SASS and there are other `reset` stylesheets available:

Eric Meyer's: https://gist.github.com/trey/3524

Hampton Catlin's: https://gist.github.com/hcatlin/1027867

`normalize` can also be used. A list of the popular `reset` and `normalize` stylesheets can be found at http://cssreset.com/.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found an answer but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it:

In _grid-settings.scss:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

I'd be interested to know if there is a better way.

Comment: This is the cleanest, fastest, most performant way to remove the margin from the page, but instead of adding it to the _grid-settings file add it to your own CSS file.

Comment: The browser is applying default styles. Have you thought about using a normalise or reset stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend adding a _reset.scss file to reset the browsers default styles. Hampton Catlin, the founder of Sass, has created this simple reset file to add to your project.

Reference: https://gist.github.com/hcatlin/1027867